# Three.js / Webgl X-RAY effect

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, three.js, webgl

How to achieve an x-ray-style effect in three.js / webgl? Some sort of this

[image]

## UPD

I need real-time render with this stuff, not a still image. This can be done with shaders, that change density in non-linear way on overlaps based on distance. I briefly understand theory, but have no practice, that is why I need help with this

Comment: Looks like it's related to 3d modelling rather than webgl - transparent materials with raytrace render, ask on 3d-related resources.

Comment: I need real-time render with this stuff, not a still image. This can be done with shaders, that change density in non-linear way on overlaps based on distance. I briefly understand theory, but have no practice, that is why I asked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, got acceptable result with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>X-ray</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.js/build/three.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.js/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/stats.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.js/examples/js/renderers/SVGRenderer.js"></script>

    <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        uniform vec3 viewVector;
        uniform float c;
        uniform float p;
        varying float intensity;
        void main()
        {
            vec3 vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
            vec3 vNormel = normalize( normalMatrix * viewVector );
            intensity = pow( c - dot(vNormal, vNormel), p );

            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        }
    </script>

    <!-- fragment shader a.k.a. pixel shader -->
    <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        uniform vec3 glowColor;
        varying float intensity;
        void main()
        {
            vec3 glow = glowColor * intensity;
            gl_FragColor = vec4( glow, 1.0 );
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            /* set margin to 0 and overflow to hidden, to go fullscreen */

            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="Stats-output">
</div>
<!-- Div which will hold the Output -->
<div id="WebGL-output">
</div>

<!-- Javascript code that runs our Three.js examples -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // once everything is loaded, we run our Three.js stuff.
    $(function () {
        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
        var human;
        camstep = 0;

        var stats = initStats();

        // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        // create a render and set the size
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});

        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1.0);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
        renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFShadowMap;


        materialCameraPosition = camera.position.clone();
        materialCameraPosition.z += 10;

        // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
        camera.position.x = -10;
        camera.position.y = 0;
        camera.position.z = 15;
        lookAt = scene.position;
        lookAt.y = 15;
        camera.lookAt(lookAt);

        // add subtle ambient lighting
        var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0c0c0c);
        //scene.add(ambientLight);


        // add the output of the renderer to the html element
        $("#WebGL-output").append(renderer.domElement);

        var customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
                {
                    uniforms: {
                        "c": { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
                        "p": { type: "f", value: 3 },
                        glowColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0x84ccff) },
                        viewVector: { type: "v3", value: materialCameraPosition }
                    },
                    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
                    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent,
                    side: THREE.FrontSide,
                    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
                    transparent: true,
                    //opacity: 0.5,
                    depthWrite: false
                });

        var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
        manager.onProgress = function (item, loaded, total) {
            console.log(item, loaded, total);
        };
        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
        loader.load('body_anatomy3.obj', function (object) {
            console.log(object);
            object.traverse(function (child) {
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    console.log(child);
                    child.material = customMaterial;
                }
            });
            object.position.y = 4;
            object.scale.x = 0.01;
            object.scale.y = 0.01;
            object.scale.z = 0.01;
            human = object;
            scene.add(human);
        });


        // call the render function
        var step = 0;
        render();

        function render() {
            stats.update();

            camstep += 0.02;

            camera.position.x = -20 * (Math.cos(camstep));
            camera.position.z = (20 * (Math.sin(camstep)));
            camera.position.y = 20;

            camera.lookAt(lookAt);

            if (human) {
                //human.rotation.y += 0.02;
                materialCameraPosition = camera.position.clone();
                materialCameraPosition.z += 10;
                human.traverse(function (child) {
                    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                        //console.log(child.material.uniforms.viewVector);
                        child.material.uniforms.viewVector.value =
                                new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(camera.position, human.position);
                    }
                });
            }

            //sphere.material.uniforms.viewVector.value = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(camera.position, sphere.position);

            // render using requestAnimationFrame
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        function initStats() {

            var stats = new Stats();

            stats.setMode(0); // 0: fps, 1: ms

            // Align top-left
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';

            $("#Stats-output").append(stats.domElement);

            return stats;
        }
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: x-ray]

Answer (score 9):

This is the as Владимир Корнилов's example except I changed the shader a little.

I'm not sure what he was going for with the `dot(vNormal, vNormel)`. Doing `abs(dot(vNormal, vec3(0, 0, 1))` will give you something that is brighter when facing toward or away from the view. Making it `1.0 - abs(dot(vNormal, vec3(0, 0, 1))` will flip that so perpendicular to the view is brighter. Then add the pow and it looks better to me but I guess that's subjective

```js
var human;

var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 0.1, 1000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1.0);

lookAt = scene.position;
lookAt.y = 15;
camera.lookAt(lookAt);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
  {
    uniforms: {
      p: { type: "f", value: 2 },
      glowColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0x84ccff) },
    },
    vertexShader: $('#vertexShader').text,
    fragmentShader: $('#fragmentShader').text,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    transparent: true,
    depthWrite: false
  });

var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load('http://greggman.github.io/doodles/assets/woman.dae', function (collada) {
  dae = collada.scene;

  dae.traverse( function ( child ) {

    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
      console.log(child);
      child.material = customMaterial;
    }

  } );

  dae.scale.x = 0.2;
  dae.scale.y = 0.2;
  dae.scale.z = 0.2;
  human = dae;
  scene.add(human);
});


function resize() {
  var canvas = renderer.domElement;
  var width  = canvas.clientWidth;
  var height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}
    
// call the render function
function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  
  resize();

  camera.position.x = -20 * (Math.cos(time));
  camera.position.z = (20 * (Math.sin(time)));
  camera.position.y = 20;

  camera.lookAt(lookAt);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r123/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="//greggman.github.io/doodles/js/three/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js"></script>

<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        uniform float p;
        varying float intensity;
        void main()
        {
            vec3 vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
            intensity = pow(1.0 - abs(dot(vNormal, vec3(0, 0, 1))), p);
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        }
</script>

<!-- fragment shader a.k.a. pixel shader -->
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        uniform vec3 glowColor;
        varying float intensity;
        void main()
        {
            vec3 glow = glowColor * intensity;
            gl_FragColor = vec4( glow, 1.0 );
        }
</script>
<style>
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
  }
  canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Your example is perfect for me, thanks! Just a question: is it possible to have transparent rather than black?

Comment: https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-tips.html#transparent-canvas

Comment: thanks but that was not actually what I was asking. I already have transparent canvas. My goal was to have the shader to go from glow color to transparent where is now showing black. However I got it by changing the frag shader from `gl_FragColor = vec4( glow, 1.0 );` to `gl_FragColor = vec4( glow, intensity );`. thanks anyways!

Comment: or even better `gl_FragColor = vec4( glow * intensity, intensity );`

Answer (score 0):

At the moment got close result with glow shader based on this demo http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Glow.html

[image]

Comment: You need to turn off backface culling or else rendering twice, once with back facing, once front backfacing. You also need to turn off the depth test. I have no idea how to do those things in Three.js but I'm sure it's in the docs

Comment: @gman take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336585/three-js-webgl-x-ray-effect/26356616#26356616